# Is there a way to open HTML cards in Picture to Picture mode (for PC)

Tags: javascript, html, picture-in-picture

I have a PIP code for video and audio files...
I just wondering is there a way to open HTML content Like Card/picture in PIP mode 
 here is my PIP for Video file...

```js
const video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
      const togglePipButton = document.getElementById('togglePipButton');
    
      // Hide button if Picture-in-Picture is not supported or disabled.
      togglePipButton.hidden = !document.pictureInPictureEnabled ||
        video.disablePictureInPicture;
    
      togglePipButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // If there is no element in Picture-in-Picture yet, let’s request
        // Picture-in-Picture for the video, otherwise leave it.
        if (!document.pictureInPictureElement) {
          video.requestPictureInPicture()
          .catch(error => {
            // Video failed to enter Picture-in-Picture mode.
          });
        } else {
          document.exitPictureInPicture()
          .catch(error => {
            // Video failed to leave Picture-in-Picture mode.
          });
        }
      });
```

```html
    <video id="myVideo" controls="" playsinline="" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/media-session/caminandes/short.mp4" poster="https://storage.googleapis.com/media-session/caminandes/artwork-512.png"></video>
    <button id="togglePipButton">tyui</button>
```

and I had came across as follows...

```html
<div class="content" id="myVideo"><img  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" alt="Lights"></div>
    <button id="togglePipButton">tyui</button>
```

with the same Script

Actually, I need help to open HTML content Like Card/picture in PIP mode

Comment: You'll want to be careful copying that much code from any source unless you know the copyright and licensing of the code. It was trivial to find https://wicg.github.io/picture-in-picture/...

Answer (score 1):

Picture-in-picture is specific only to Chrome (it doesn't work in any other browser), and is specific to Video elements. It's not a mode for anything else or anywhere else. But for HTML elements, you can get the same effect using the CSS `position: fixed` property.

For instance:

```css
.pip {
  position: fixed;
  right: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 4px;
}

/* Below is just for demo; it's only the above that's relevant. */
pre {
  font-size: 20pt;
}
```

```html
<div class='pip'>This is a Picture-in-Picture-like element.</div>
<pre>Some
large
text
to
make
the
window
scroll
so
you
can
see
the
Picture-
in-
Picture
will
remain
in
the
same
spot.</pre>
```

If you want to turn it on/off with a click, you can add or remove the pip class from the element as needed, using `element.classList.add('pip')` and `element.classList.remove('pip')`.

Answer (score -1):

try using this

```js
const video = document.querySelectorAll('video')[0];
    const button = document.querySelector('button');
    
    
    if (!document.pictureInPictureEnabled) {
      button.textContent = 'PiP is not supported in your browser.';
      button.style.opacity = '0.5';
      button.style.cursor = 'default';
      button.disabled = true;
    }
    
    video.addEventListener('enterpictureinpicture', () => {
        button.textContent = 'Exit Picture-in-Picture';
    });
    
    video.addEventListener('leavepictureinpicture', () => {
        button.textContent = 'Enter Picture-in-Picture';
    });
    
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (document.pictureInPictureElement) {
        document.exitPictureInPicture()
      } else {
        video.requestPictureInPicture()
      }
    });
```

```css
     html {
         -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
         -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
    }
     *, *:before, *:after {
         -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
         -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
         box-sizing: inherit;
    }
     body {
         padding: 2rem;
         font-family: 'Inter UI', sans-serif;
         text-align: center;
         position: relative;
    }
     h1, h2 {
         margin-top: 0;
    }
     .wrapper {
         width: 100vw;
         height: 100vh;
         display: flex;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: center;
         flex-direction: column;
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
    }
     video {
         margin-bottom: 32px;
    }
     .button {
         height: 40px;
         line-height: 40px;
         padding: 0 2rem;
         border-radius: 4px;
         background: #2b8dff;
         color: #fff;
         display: inline-block;
         font-size: 17px;
         font-weight: 500;
         border: none;
         outline: none;
         cursor: pointer;
    }
     .button-full {
         width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
     <div class="wrapper">
      <video 
        src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
        controls
      ></video>
      
      <button type="button" class="button js-open">Enter Picture-in-Picture</button>
    </div>
```